# Existence of Gaussian measures on separable Banach space

Tags: measure-theory, gaussian-measure

I am reading about Gaussian measure on infinite dimensional spaces in *Bogachev's Gaussian Measures (1998) - Chapter 2*. In it, the notion of Gaussian measure on a locally convex space $X$ is given in *Definition 2.2.1*, and *Theorem 2.3.1* proves the existence of Gaussian measures on separable Hilbert spaces.

My question is about the existence of Gaussian measures on more generalized spaces, for example, on separable Banach spaces. I have been looking up to other references, but so far, I haven't found any better result than the existence on Hilbert space.